# Tao, Analysis I: Exercise 8.5.14. Prove Zorn's Lemma.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, set-theory, order-theory

Please help me locate errors :(

Proposition(Zorn's Lemma): Let $X\neq\emptyset$ be of partial order with the property that $\forall Y\subseteq X$ such that $Y$ is of total-order then $Y$ has an upperbound, then $X$ contains a maximal element.

Proof:
Case 1: $B\neq\emptyset$ such that $B$=$\{$$b\in X$: $b$ has an undefined order relation with all elements in $X$$\}$. Thus, $\forall b\in B$, $b$ is maximal since there is no $x\in X$ where $b<x$.

Case 2: $B=\emptyset$; Let $I_1$ be some index set and let $Y_\alpha,\forall\alpha\in X_1$ denote all the totally-ordered sets in $X$. Consider that $\cup_{\alpha\in I_1}Y_\alpha$ is either a poset or a totally-ordered set in $X$. If $\cup_{\alpha\in I_1}Y_\alpha$ is totally ordered, then, by the premise of the lemma, $\cup_{\alpha\in I_1}Y_\alpha$ has an upperbound $\hat{y}$. Since $\hat{y}$ would then be an upperbound of all totally-ordered subsets of $X$, then no $x\in X$ satisfies $\hat{y}<x$. Hence, $\hat{y}$ is a maximal element in $X$. If $\cup_{\alpha\in I_1}Y_\alpha$ is a poset, then $\exists y_1,y_2\in\cup_{\alpha\in I_1}Y_\alpha$ such that the order relation $y_1$ and $y_2$ is undefined. In order to resolve this issue(of being unable to "compare"), we construct a set $\mathscr{T}$ of totally-ordered sets $\Bbb{T}(y)$ where $\forall\overline{y}\in\cup_{\alpha\in I_1}Y_\alpha$, we let \begin{align}\Bbb{T}(\overline{y})=\{y\in\cup_{\alpha\in I_1}Y_\alpha:y\leq_X\overline{y}\quad \lor\quad \overline{y}\leq_X y\}\end{align}
Note that the correspondence of each $\overline{y}\in\cup_{\alpha\in I_1}Y_\alpha$ to a set $\Bbb{T}(\overline{y})$ is not one-to-one. Nevertheless, we have a collection $\mathscr{T}=\{\Bbb{T}(y):y\in\cup_{\alpha\in I_1}Y_\alpha\}=\{\Bbb{T}(y):y\in X\}$. Each $\Bbb{T}(y)$ is constructed in such a way so that $\forall\alpha\in I_1, \exists\Bbb{T}(y)\in\mathscr{T}$ such that $Y_\alpha\subseteq\Bbb{T}(y)$. Moreover, since $B=\emptyset$ and $\forall y\in\cup_{\alpha\in I_1}Y_\alpha$, $\Bbb{T}(y)$ contains the maximum number of elements from $X$ while remaining totally-ordered, then $\forall x_i\in X$ where $x_i\notin\Bbb{T}(y)$, it must be that $x_i\in\Bbb{T}(y')$ where $y$ and $y'$ have an undefined order-relation. Lastly, since we know that $\forall y\in X, \Bbb{T}(y)\subseteq X$ and is totally-ordered, then, by our premise, $\Bbb{T}(y)$ has an upperbound $\tau$ which I think is some maximal of $X$ because all upperbounds of each distinct $\Bbb{T}(y^*)\in\mathscr{T}$ are pair-wise undefined order relation(or incomparable). So for all upperbound $\tau$ in some $\Bbb{T}(y)$ there does not exist $x\in X$ such that $\tau <x$.

Comment: There are several questions on the site with proofs of Zorn's Lemma. How about you look at those, and then try to figure out what you did wrong?

Comment: there are so many of them. where should i start looking?

Comment: Any of which that include a proof of Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: ZL has numerous equivalent statements. Do you assume axiom of choice?

Comment: I would like to say yes, however I'm not yet well-verse with it so I, honestly, could not tell for sure, unfortunately :(

Comment: What is an upperbound of upper bounds? Does such an element always exist?!

Comment: If you're not even sure what kind of choice assumptions you are making, this exercise is not suited for you.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: What I meant was in a set $U$ of upperbounds found from distinct totally ordered subsets in $X$ then the upperbound of $U$ is the like the "upperbound of upperbounds" sorry for that if that sounded crazy and stupid

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I won't disagree. The section on set theory in Tao's text is quite short. The elementary set theory I am acquainted is from quantifier logic up until functions and order relations.

Comment: this suck since I toiled my entire afternoon to no avail :(

Comment: (1) If you're interested in set theory, try a different source (e.g. Enderton's book). If you're interested in analysis, you can probably skip the set theory for now and use it as a black box instrument wherever it appears in the proofs. (2) Toiling for nothing [is not a waste of time](http://karagila.org/2018/in-praise-of-failure/).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thank you for the book recommendation. I will most definitely try it out. I appreciate your kind words! :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila In praise of failure is a good point to make and illustrates the priorities of an undergrad student. I did discrete math in grad school, since I didn't have it in undergrad. Of course I criticise some of the exercises, which is justified. But it's because I have understood mathematical logic (just because you learn in it in discrete math doesn't mean you'll understand it the same semester).
Without logic, independent thought in mathematics is difficult if not nigh impossible :o

Answer (score 1):

**Case1.** Assume $X$ is itself totally ordered.
You write: 
*thus for a fixed element $b\in B$, $b$ is maximal.*

Well, of course, you assumed $B=\emptyset$. What ever you claim for an element of $B$ is vacuously true, since there are no elements to check the condition against. No further justification is required.

We are still short a maximal element, however.

**Case2**. Do point out that $X$ does contain totally ordered subsets. For instance, since $X\neq\emptyset$, every singleton subset is totally ordered.

If we observe the union of all totally ordered subsets: $\bigcup Y_j \subseteq X$ and assume this is totally ordered, then we have assumed $X$ is totally ordered. Back to **Case1**.

The set $\mathbb T(y)$ is a chain in $X$ generated by $y$. $\mathbb T(x) = \mathbb T(y)$ iff $x,y$ are comparable i.e they are situated in the same chain. By premise of ZL the set $\mathbb T(y), y\in X$ is bounded. No maximal element in sight.

Your assumptions are too weak.

An alternative, is to assume the Axiom of Choice and proceed by [this proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom_of_Choice_Implies_Zorn%27s_Lemma) : AC implies ZL. Study proof 2, for it is far less involved.

Reading your post, I also get the feeling you mis-understand something about ZL. It doesn't say how many maximal elements there are. It certainly doesn't tell you the upper bound itself is a maximal element!

Comment: Thank you for your time. Why wouldn't all other upperbounds not be in $\cup Y_j\subseteq X$? I was thinking that if $\beta$ is some other upperbound which was not included in $\cup Y_j\subseteq X$ and knowing that $\beta$ is an upperbound means there exist $x_0\in X$ such that $x_0<\beta$? So $\{x_0,\beta\}$ is a totally-ordered subset and must be in $\cup Y_j\subseteq X$. What am I missing here? Thank you again!

Comment: Your example with $S=\bigcup_{P\in\cal P}P$ is odd. *Every* member of $X$ is a member of a chain. So $S=X$. So your argument shows that $X$ is totally ordered. Of course, this is not true, just look at $\{0,1\}$ with the identity order.

Comment: @AsafKaragila uhh, right. I will remind myself of the correct construction.

Comment: There is no way to "construct" this, you have to appeal to some magical witchcraft theorem that produces some intangible object. If you could construct the maximal objects, you could have proved the axiom of choice from ZF.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, now I remember the witchcraft. Its results are completely different compared to the expectations of the OP.

Comment: @TheLastCipher Asaf Karagila also pointed this out. If you take the union of all totally ordered subsets, you get $\bigcup Y_j = \bigcup _{x\in X} \{x\} = X$. $X$ doesn't have to be a chain, so the upper bound argument becomes meaningless.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: Yes. I also encountered this fact during my proof sketches. But I never intended to apply upperbound on $\cup Y_j$, because of what Asaf pointed out. What I instead was trying to do is "sorting" the chains together. My set $\mathscr{T}$ is the set of chains $\Bbb{T}(y)$. The correspondence of each element $y\in X$ to a chain $\Bbb(y)$ is not one-to-one, but I thought it wouldn't matter since I am putting it in a set $\mathscr{T}$ to cancel redundancy like how $\{a,a\}=\{a\}$. Lastly, I picked each of the upperbound of each chain $\Bbb{T}(y)$ in $\mathscr{T}$.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: (cont..)Finally, I thought that the upperbound of each chain are pairwise incomparable and no other elements in their repective chains are "greater" than them so I thought they could be the maximal elements.

Comment: @TheLastCipher You can have chains that have the same upper bound(s). There is still no obvious way to find a maximal element in the whole set.

Comment: @AlvinLepik: I agree that they can have the same upperbound. But if they're not the same then they're either incomparable or must be together in some chain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78247/discussion-between-alvin-lepik-and-thelast-cipher).