# Axiom of Choice implies Hausdorff Maximality Principle

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, order-theory

Checking for a classmate. Here is his proof.

Proof:
Let $C$ be the set of chains(linearly ordered subsets) in $X$. Pick an $A\in C$ where $A$ is not necessarily a maximal chain. Define $S:=\{\beta\in C:A\subseteq\beta\}$. Then $\bigcup S$ is a maximal chain in $X$.
EDIT: I think Axiom of Choice is used in picking elements of $S$.

I feel that one reason this might be incorrect is $S$ might not have a maximal element...?

Comment: when did you pick elements of $S$? The axiom of choice is used in showing that $S$ does indeed have a maximal element (so you're right, that's the gap).

Comment: Okay. thanks and if you don't mind, may you provide a rough sketch on how Axiom of Choice could show that $S$ does indeed have a maximal element? My understanding is axiom of choice can choose the elements for $S$, but as to how it reveals a maximal element remains a mystery to me.

Comment: Oh. I think we could say that we used axiom of choice to pick elements of $S$ from the power set of $X$?

Comment: First I missed something: "$\cup S$ is a maximal chain in $X$" No. There's no reason to even expect that would be a chain. A maximal element of $S$ would be the chain you're looking for. Note this is a completely different ordering than the original one (it is the partial ordering of $S$ by inclusion). The most straightforward way to show the maximal element of $S$ exists is to show that every chain in $S$ has an upper bound and use Zorn's lemma.

Comment: I missed that one too! It's in the corner of my mind's eye for a while and couldn't seem to find it again! thank you!!

Comment: You're repeating the same mistakes from [last time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2802880/tao-analysis-i-exercise-8-5-14-prove-zorns-lemma).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes. Zorn's lemma has to be proven first. That's why the problem looked very familiar lol. I'm planning to read enderton's book. It's just that our analysis professor gave this as homework even without discussing the details of the proposition aside from reading the statement in front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the domain of $A$ is $\emptyset.$ Then $S=C,$ but $\cup C$ is not a chain in $X$ unless $X$ has at most $1$ member, because if $x,x'\in X$ with $x\ne x'$ then there exist two incompatible linear orders on $\{x,x'\}.$

Any $c\in C$ is equal to $(S_c,<_c)$ where $S_c\subset X$ and where $<_c$ is a linear order on $S_c.$ For $c,d\in C$ let $$c<^*d \iff (S_c\subsetneq S_d\land \forall x,y\in S_c\;(x<_cy\iff x<_d y)).$$

For any $a\in C$ let $F(a)=\{a\}\cup \{c\in C:a<^*c\}.$

Observe that $<^*$ is transitive and irreflexive on $F(a)$ and that if $B$ is a non-empty $<^*$ chain of members of $F(a)$ then $\cup B \in F(a),$ and  $\cup B$ is a $<^*$-upper bound for $B.$ And that $F(a)\ne \emptyset$, as $a\in F(a)$.

So by Zorn's Lemma there exists  $c\in F(a)$ which is $<^*$-maximal among members of $F(a).$ Then it is almost trivial to show  that $S_c=X$, so $c$ is a maximal member of $C$.

That is, if $X$ has a subset $S_a$ that  can be linearly ordered then any linear order on  $S_a$ can be extended to a linear order on $X.$

Since we could take $S_a=\emptyset,$ we also find that every $X$ (and, a fortiori, every $S_a\subset X$) can be linearly ordered.

BTW, it has been shown that, in the absence of Choice (Zorn), the axiom that every set can be linearly ordered does  $not$  imply the axiom of Choice.